# Tool to check performance/optimize ASP.NET Windows Application

Tags: asp.net, windows

I have a ASP.NET windows application and need to test its performance. It basically captures images and sends to the server by Web Services.

Can anyone suggest me some good tools to analyze the performance of my application ?

**Updated:** I do not have the code for the application. I am already trying to predict using Fiddler as far as performance for Web services.

My Bad: I am working on Windows Application for the first time, and this is just the analysis work.

Comment: "Questions asking us to recommend or find a tool, library or favorite off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, [describe the problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/139399/) and what has been done so far to solve it." Reference: [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio itself provides many useful performance profiling features. [Beginners Guide to Performance Profiling](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182372.aspx)

I'm assuming by "ASP.NET windows application" you mean a Windows application communicating with an ASP.NET application through web services.

Answer (score 0):

Red gate's Ant's profiler does a superb job in profiling asp.net /MVC apps. Try their trial and you will know.

http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/ants-performance-profiler/

Comment: I dont have the code, just the installed application.
Will it work with that ?